# TensorRT for upscaling images serves not expected results

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pycuda, tensorrt

I'm fighting with TensorRT (TensorRT 4 for python right now) since several weeks. I passed a lot of problems to get TensorRT running. The example code from NVIDIA works well for me :
[TensorRT MNIST example](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-api/topics/topics/workflows/tf_to_tensorrt.html)

Now, i created my own network in tensorflow (a very simple one) for upscaling images, let's say (in HWC) 320x240x3 into 640x480x3 .The usual way by creating a frozen-graph and running an inferencer just based on Tensorflow gave me expected results but not by using TensorRT.

I have a strange feeling about that i made something wrong by feeding the images into the GPU-memory (This would be probably an issue about pycuda and/or TensorRT).

The worst case scenario would be that TensorRT destroys my network by the optimization process.

I hope someone has just a little idea for saving my life.
This is my Tensorflow-model (i just wrapped the functions):

```
net = conv2d(input,
             64,
             k_size=3,
             activation=tf.nn.relu,
             name='conv1')

net = deconv2d(net,
               3,
               k_size=5,
               activation=tf.tanh,
               stride=self.params.resize_factor,
               scale=self.params.resize_factor,
               name='deconv')
```

This is the important snippet of my inferencer:

```
import tensorrt as trt
import uff
from tensorrt.parsers import uffparser
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import numpy as np
...

def _init_infer(self, uff_model):

   g_logger = trt.infer.ConsoleLogger(trt.infer.LogSeverity.ERROR)

   parser = uffparser.create_uff_parser()
   parser.register_input(self.input_node, (self.channels, self.height, self.width), 0)
   parser.register_output(self.output_node)

   self.engine = trt.utils.uff_to_trt_engine(g_logger, uff_model, parser, self.max_batch_size,
                                              self.max_workspace_size)

   parser.destroy()

   self.runtime = trt.infer.create_infer_runtime(g_logger)
   self.context = self.engine.create_execution_context()

   self.output = np.empty(self.output_size, dtype=self.dtype)

   # create CUDA stream
   self.stream = cuda.Stream()

   # allocate device memory
   self.d_input = cuda.mem_alloc(self.channels * self.max_batch_size * self.width *
                                  self.height * self.output.dtype.itemsize)
   self.d_output = cuda.mem_alloc(self.output_size * self.output.dtype.itemsize)

   self.bindings = [int(self.d_input), int(self.d_output)]

def infer(self, input_batch, batch_size=1):

    # transfer input data to device
    cuda.memcpy_htod_async(self.d_input, input_batch, self.stream)
    # execute model
    self.context.enqueue(batch_size, self.bindings, self.stream.handle, None)
    # transfer predictions back
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(self.output, self.d_output, self.stream)
    # synchronize threads
    self.stream.synchronize()

    return self.output
```

And the executable snippet:

```
...
# create trt inferencer
trt_inferencer = TensorRTInferencer(params=params)

img = [misc.imread('./test_images/lion.png')]
img[0] = normalize(img[0])
img = img[0]

# inferencing method
result = trt_inferencer.infer(img)
result = inormalize(result, dtype=np.uint8)

result = result.reshape(1, params.height * 2, params.width * 2, 3)
...
```

And the weird result by comparison :(
[upscaled lion TensorRT, Tensorflow, Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89rhW.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I got it now, finally. The problem was a wrong dimension and order of the input images and output. And for everyone who run into the same problem, this is the adopted executable snippet, dependent on my initialization:

```
...
# create trt inferencer
trt_inferencer = TensorRTInferencer(params=params)

img = [misc.imread('./test_images/lion.png')]
img[0] = normalize(img[0])
img = img[0]

img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1))
img = img.ravel()

# inferencing method
result = trt_inferencer.infer(img)
result = inormalize(result, dtype=np.uint8)

result = np.reshape(result, newshape=[3, params.height * 2, params.width * 2])
result = np.transpose(result, (1, 2, 0))
...
```